# How to record guitar or harp for building a sample suite

Tags: guitar, recording

I would like to produce a suite of guitar or harp sounds to make a set of primitive samples. The lowest level samples or components you would need to be able to write music with a keyboard using these samples.

My question is, what roughly do you need to record to make it sound realistic coming from a keyboard? Do you need to record every possible note, or can you just record everything in say “middle C” and then use software of some sort to gonvert those notes into every pitch? What about (on a guitar) sliding between notes, how should you record that? Or bending. Do you just need to record one bend and then you can generate the rest programmatically?

I don’t need to know every aspect, just roughly some guidelines to follow to get quality results. Thank you for the introduction.

Comment: When sampling any instrument, record a few notes in different registers, listen to whether they still sound natural transposed 1, 2, 3... semitones up or down, and then decide how many samples per octave you need. Recording every third note (i.e. 4 notes per octave) and transposing 1 semitone up and down often works. (Guitar has the added problem that a note can be played on different strings and sound different.)

Comment: This is basically the same question as https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/87502/what-sort-of-samples-you-need-to-record-for-a-good-flute-sample-pack just replacing the word 'flute' with 'guitar'. The answer  is almost identical.

Comment: Were you hoping to find COTS s/w to get the other notes or write your own?  The instrument responds differently at different registers (at least for acoustics).  Since you can make an electric sound any way you want with effects you are really sampling the amp+guitar system.